# Possible to have a function take a char array of set length?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to keep a highscore table for my Arduino game and have the following method to add a new high score. The problem is `names` is declared as `names[positions][4]` so each name should be exactly three characters or who knows what might happen. Do I need to check it manually in the function, or can I enforce it in the definition, or should I use a whole different approach altogether?

```
void Highscore::add(uint8_t score, const char * name)
{
    position = Highscore::getPosition(score);

    if (position >= positions) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i=positions-1; i<=position; i--) {
        scores[i] = scores[i-1];
        names[i] = names[i-1];
    }

    scores[position] = score;
    names[position] = name;

    Highscore::save();
}
```

Comment: `names[position] = name;` :o Use strcpy. And yes, you´ll have to check it

Comment: why not use `strlen` or some other function to check the length of `name`, and if it is more than 3, then ask to enter it again.

Comment: As you're using C++, what's wrong with using std::string?

Comment: The checking should have already been done by the view, so I should have exactly 3 characters, but I was just wondering how I would deal with the error condition here in the model. ie, trim to 3 characters if to long, pad with 'a' if to short, or just throw some kind of exception... c++ is quite new to me

Comment: then I suggest that you use `std::string`. It'll help you with your objectives.

Comment: G. Ko - std::string isn't available when compiling for Arduino, it's a very cutdown subset of c++

Comment: "So each name should be exactly three characters" but you have length 4 arrays. So you really mean 4 characters, including the null-terminator, right?

Comment: Also you could use Arduino's `String` class, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a c-string stored as an array of char cannot be copied, passed as argument by value,  or  compared like build-in scalar type.

**Solution 1:** use **[`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/?kw=string)** instead of `char[4]`. **That's the recommended C++ way**. They are extremeley easy and intuitive to use, and they have no real length restriction.  But if you desire to limit their length, you can control it at user entry.

**Solution 2:** if you can't use solution 1, because of technical limitations of an embedded system, you could use a structure/class for holding the string.  Here a templatized version:

```
template <int N>
struct fstring {
    char s[N+1];                // fixed string
    fstring() : s{} {}          // create an empty string
    fstring(const char*st) {    // convert a c-string to a fixed string
        strncpy(s, st, N);
        s[N] = 0;
    }
    bool operator== (fstring x) // compare two strings 
    {
        return strncmp(s, x.s, N) == 0;
    }
};
... 
fstring<3> names[10];  // ten fixed strings
```

**Solution 3:** You can keep your data structures exactly as they are, but use `strncpy()` instead of assignment, and `strcmp()` instead of comparison.